# Posting limitations broken?

Tags: bug, questions

I attempted to post a question (at 4:45pm EST) on stackoverflow and it says "can only post every 90 min's" and the last time I posted a question was 10 hours ago.

anyone know whats going on or how to fix that?

Comment: 1. Did someone else used this computer? Maybe it's IP based and not account based 2. It might be broken nonetheless.

Comment: Nah this was on my personal network and my computer has maintained the same ip (static) since 24hrs ago

Comment: Bah I managed to post my question now but that was via my phone.

Comment: @Pariah that's only more indication that it's IP related.

Comment: Yeah i'm aware, i wasn't completely ruling out ip, only a little confused because i have a static address, but then again i should of considered NAT translation